# What is the Best practice for Global Variable Declaration in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React.js and currently on a project using React.js which needs to make api calls to back end server.

May I know what is the best way to declare global variables in react.js project.

Your kind guidance is highly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Redux for state management?

Comment: Not yet using Redux.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is not good practice use global variable if you doesn't have to. My suggestion is when you have not to use it is much better use some state machine like Redux. And store all objects into state.

Or if you need global variable there is no differences than common js project.

In html you can define global variable like i do in Index.cshtml to init redux state:

```
 <script>
        var initialReduxState = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
 </script>
```

Or when I have to use third party script so in my middle-ware i am initializing global variable like:

```
var freshDeskobj= new fresDesk();
window["freshDesk"] = freshDeskobj;
```

Than I am able use it as

```
window["freshDesk"].someMethod();
```

But is good to check for existence first.

When you need care when global variable is created and you have to also dispose it is good approach to create component and use life cycle hooks. Simply create component. Place it somewhere in layout (be sure that this component will exist one). And in component you can use life cycle methods componentWillMount() create global variable in it and in componentWillUnmount() you can dispose resource. In render method simply return null.

Answer (score 0):

I managed with a simple solution which is declaring variable in the index.html. Thanks!